# Is it possible to scale <MapView.Circle /> as zoom is increased and decreased?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to get  to decrease in size as I zoom in, and increase in size as I zoom out.
I have an inner circle and an outer circle. Resizing the outer circle isnt important, but I would really like to make the inner circle scale with zoom.
Is this even possible?

```
<MapView style={{ flex: 1 }} region={region}>
    <MapView.Circle
      center={{
        longitude: location.longitude,
        latitude: location.latitude,
      }}
      radius={1000}
      strokeWidth={2}
      strokeColor={MAIN_BLUE}
      fillColor={TRANSPARENT_BLUE}
    />
    <MapView.Circle
      center={{
        longitude: location.longitude,
        latitude: location.latitude,
      }}
      radius={50}
      strokeColor={MAIN_BLUE}
      fillColor={MAIN_BLUE}
    />
    {markers &&
      markers.map(marker => (
        <MapView.Marker
          key={marker.id}
          coordinate={marker.latlng}
          title={marker.name}
          description={marker.description}
        />
      ))}
  </MapView>
```